# C# Insert ArrayList in DataRow

Tags: c#

I want to insert an arraylist in Datarow.

using this code,

```
      ArrayList array=new ArrayList();
      foreach (string s in array) 
      {
           valuesdata.Rows.Add(s);
      }
```

But My datatable must have only one datarow. My code created eight datarows.
I tried,

```
valuesdata.Rows.Add(array);
```

But it doesn't work.That should be

```
valuesdata.Rows.Add(array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3]....);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Your array has nothing in it, so of course indexing into it will fail. Put some data in the `array` variable first.

Comment: No...This code only for example.Array isn't empty...

Comment: C# is not Java. You should be using `List<string>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
        ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

        String[] arrayB = new String[array.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            arrayB[i] = array[i].ToString();
        }

        valuesdata.Rows.Add(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 3):

try like this:

```
//1 - declare the array ArrayList object
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

//2 - here add some elements into your array object

//3 - convert the ArrayList to string array and pass it as ItemArray to Rows.Add
valuesdata.Rows.Add(array.ToArray(typeof(string)));
```